# Which abilities are shared in One For All?

Tags: league-of-legends

If a team is playing Akali and one puts down the shroud, does everyone go stealth? What about other similar skills such as Nocturne's Q? What about team buffs?

Comment: I can confirm, at least, that buff abilities (such as Gangplank's E) do not stack with themselves.

Comment: I found out as Ziggs, your Satchel Charge will knockback other Ziggs on your team if they're in explosion radius. So it's quite possible  Akali's can shroud each other, still needs to be tested though. I remember they changed Nocturne's Q just for OFA but I ca't remember what the change was.

Comment: Brand's stun on his Q works for any other's passive on effect ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Skills that work with teammates

- **Akali's Twilight Shroud** also hides other friendly Akalis.
- **Anivia's Frostbite** will do double damage to an enemy that is 'chilled' by another friendly Anivia.
- **Brand's abilities** will all gain their passive effect if a friendly Brand's Immolation is on that enemy.
- **Cassiopeia's Twin Fang** will be set to a .5 CD if it hits any enemy poisoned by another friendly Cassiopeia (Also goes for Teemo/Singed Poison when not in OFA).
- **Darius** gains movement speed from his passive for bleeding enemies, no matter which Darius applied the bleeding stacks.
- **Diana's Moonlight** An allied Diana can use others Diana's Moonlight for her Lunar Rush.
- **Draven** may catch another friendly(or foe) Draven's Spinning Axe.
- **Jarvan IV** using friendly Jarvan's Demacian Standard to Dragon Strike towards.
- **Jayce's Acceleration Gate** will boost the power of all friendly Jayce's Shock Blasts.
- **Kennen's Mark of the Storm** stacks no matter which Kennen applies them.
- **LeBlanc's Sigil of Silence** can be procced by friendly LeBlancs (including another LeBlanc's Sigil of Silence).
- **Leona** can proc friendly Leonas' passive.
- **Lux** can detonate the passive from any other friendly Lux.
- **Maokai's Vengeful Maelstrom** 5 of those ulti's will make everybody inside almost unkillable.
- **Nocturne's Duskbringer** Will increase friendly Nocturne's stats.
- **Quinn** can proc any friendly Quinn's Harrier
- **Syndra** can use all friendly Syndra's orbs as if they were her own.
- **Twitch's Deadly Venom** can stack with other Twitch's Deadly Venom and be procced by a friendly Twitch's Expunge.
- **Urgot's Acid Hunter** will lock on to a target hit by another Urgot's Noxian Corrosive Charge.
- **Varus' Blighted Quiver** can stack and be procced by friendly Varus' abilities.
- **Vayne** can stack on and proc friendly Vayne's Silver Bolts
- **Vi** can stack on and proc other Vi's Denting Blows
- **Zigg's Satchel Charge** launches other friendly Ziggs upon detonation.
- **Zilean's Time Bomb** will explode instantly if another Zilean places a bomb on the same target.
- **Zyra** can create plants from friendly Zyras' seeds

### Skills that do not work with teammates

- **Passive auras** Buffs like Heimer's passive or Janna's passive don't stack.
- **Akali's Mark of the Assassin** cannot be triggered by another friendly Akali.
- **Katarina's Bouncing Blade Mark** cannot be triggered by another friendly Katarina.
- **Mordekaisers** cannot stack their ultimate. If attempted, the skill does nothing but the cooldown resets.
- **Sejuani's Permafrost active** doesn't affect enemies with Permafrost from another Sejuani.
- **Xerath's Mage Chains Stun** cannot be triggered by another friendly Xerath.
- **Zac** can only pick up his own blobs that drop when using abilities.

---

---

### Possible Skill Interactions (*Untested*)

- **Ahri's Charm** increasing damage of friendly Ahri's.
- **Darius' Hemorrhage** Increases damage of friendly Darius' Ults.
- **Swain's Torment** incresing damage dealt by friendly Swains.
- **Thresh's The Box** damaging and enemy only once no matter how many different Thresh walls they break.
- **Vladimir's Hemoplague** Either refreshing the duration or stacking for more increased damage.

Comment: Please edit and add your findings :)

Comment: Did a game as Kennen, his Mark of the Storm does NOT stack like Vayne's W does, they proc independently, and there is no diminishing return on stuns initiated by different players.

Comment: I disagree with @WoF's comment. I played a One For All game as Kennen. If one Kennen hit Q and then others hit W, it would stun. Important note: multiple Kennen ults cannot hit the same target more than 3 times except when spaced out.

Comment: As a slightly offtopic comment: doesn't Jarvan's pull work with wards as well?

Comment: @Joetjah no, Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @SirKsilem I might have done it some time by accident, but I could also be mistaken and I have actually never tried it after that again.